# Getting Bitmaps from each frame of an Android video source

Tags: android, video, bitmap, camera

I am currently referring to Android's Camera SDK: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

I am working on an ASCII camera app for a school project. Say this camera takes video in 30 FPS, I am interested in taking each frame and converting it to ASCII. I have already created the ASCII algorithm, and it works on `Bitmap` objects (it takes each `Color` object of the `Bitmap`, and through its range within the `Color` spectrum, it's assigned a `char`, such as `@` or `O`, etc).

I am having trouble looking through this SDK. How do I take each individual frame of this video source and get an object type that I can work with, such as a `Bitmap`?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29

Comment: That does not really answer my question, however. How do I manipulate each frame?

Comment: The frames are delivered to your `onPreviewFrame()` method of your `Camera.PreviewCallback`. You will need to either modify your algorithm to use the `byte[]` you are given, or  you will need to transform the `byte[]` into something that you can use.